# Failing to correct a simple rounding error

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

I have a small script which arranges a budget into a monthly format another software accepts. The script works mostly fine, except that some numbers aren't divisible by 12. I'm having trouble correcting that.

The table originally looks something like:
[image]

..and when the script is run, the table turns to:
[image]

..for a total sum of **12 999.60** - not the original **13 000.00**. The difference may look a bit trivial, but the numbers are in tens of thousands so they do unfortunately matter a lot.

I did think I could account for the rounding error though by taking the total rounded number and subtracting the original number in the last entry, which may sound like a clunky solution but it's OK, but this gave the following result:
[image]

..which is a total of **13 003.60**. I could be going about this all wrong and the solution may be stupid simple, for which I ask you to forgive my incompetence, but this is the code with the attempted correction:

```
'For each budget post..'
For Each row In rng.Rows
            
    Dim i As Long
            
    'Decimal count var'
    Dim countDec As Long
    countDec = 0
            
    'Repeat twelve times'
    For i = 1 To 12
        'Test if row is empty'
        If Len(Range("A" & x).Value) > 0 Then
            'Add the current periods number to the variable..'
            countDec = countDec + Round(Range("D" & x).Value / 12, 1)
                
            'New values to cells'
            Cells(j, 6).Value = Range("A" & x).Value 'Account'
            Cells(j, 7).Value = i 'Period value +1'
            Cells(j, 8).Value = Range("C" & x).Value 'Cst'
                    
            'Correct decimal on 12th iteration'
            If i = 12 Then
                countDec = countDec - Range("D" & x).Value 'Count the difference between the total periods and the original value'
                Cells(j, 9).Value = Round(Range("D" & x).Value / 12, 1) + countDec '1/12th plus sum of decimal difference'
            ElseIf i <> 12 Then
                Cells(j, 9).Value = Round(Range("D" & x).Value / 12, 1) 'If not last iteration, just print rounded period value'
            End If
                    
            j = j + 1
                    
        End If
    Next i
    x = x + 1
Next row
```

Comment: Please add Option Explicit. j is not defined anywhere ...

Comment: @StureS Hi. It is, I've just cut the code snippet short because there's a lot of other things going on in the script aswell. `Dim j As Long` `j = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `If i = 12` clause:

```
If i = 12 Then
    Cells(j, 9).Value = Range("D" & x).Value - Round(Range("D" & x).Value / 12, 1) * 11
```

Comment: Even though I always end up feeling a little dumb, this is why I love this community. Thank you * 1000.